# Retrieve only checkboxes that have been checked vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have this loop that checks weather checkboxes have been checked or not, but the array that this loop creates stores every single checkbox value of the list of checkboxes regardless if it is checked or not. So, I am not sure how to create a second loop that will gather only the checkboxes that have been checked out of the array SelectedItemArray1(i). Thank you very much for your help in advance and this is what I have so far.

```
 For i = 0 To Sheet1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Sheet1.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        SelectedItemArray1(i) = Sheet1.ListBox1.List(i)
    End If

    MsgBox SelectedItemArray1(i)
 Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested) code and see how well it works for you:

```
Dim Msg As String
Dim i As Integer
If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
    Msg = "Nothing"
Else
    Msg = ""
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

If your list box allows multi-selection of check boxes, then it's a different kind of animal. I did some googling and found [this article](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/635299-visual-basic-applications-code-selected-item-listbox.html), which should hopefully give you some ideas. Also, take a look at [this article](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=369), which seems more complete.

---

**EDIT:**

I thought it might help to give the multi-select code too, from the first article I linked:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim msg As String
Dim arrItems() As String
ReDim arrItems(0 To ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1)
For j = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(j) Then
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1
            arrItems(i) = ListBox1.Column(i, j)
        Next i
        msg = msg & Join(arrItems, ",") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End If
Next j
MsgBox msg
```

Comment: Thank you djikay. Yes it allows multiple selections. I will read the article.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thank you very much djikay. This will do.

Comment: This did the job. Thank you very much. I appreciate your help.